# Extract area and sector from uk postcode python

Tags: python, pandas, postal-code

I was wondering if anyone could help me extracting area and sector in Python using pandas?

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) For questions about panda, start with providing your dataframe including testdata _and_ show your expected & gotten results. Try to solve it yourself first.

Comment: `I was wondering if anyone could help me extracting area and sector in Python using pandas?` Yes, someone can help you.